# Video.js gives error "The media could not be loaded because the server or network failed..."

Tags: html, video, video.js

I'm trying to make a video play using Video.js on Mac OS X.  This does not work on all common browsers.  Safari, Firefox, Opera and Google Chrome.  I'm not sure if it only works when you're loading it from a server, but the way I'm doing is just drag and drop my HTML file on the tab place on the browser.  This is what I have in my `<video>` tag.

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
         controls preload="auto" width="880" height="495" 
         poster="/assets/poster.png" data-setup="{}" autoplay>
    <source src="/assets/TheMagicPortal.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
    <source src="/assets/TheMagicPortal.webm" type='video/webm'/>
    <track kind="captions" src="assets/subtitles.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default>
    <track kind="subtitles" src="assets/subtitles-fr.vtt" srclang="fr" label="Français">
    <track kind="subtitles" src="assets/subtitles-jp.vtt" srclang="ja" label="日本語">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video.</a></p>
  </video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put single quotes instead of double quotes in my `<source>` tag!  How did I miss that??!

Comment: which field had the wrong quotes? why did it matter? from everything I can tell, single quotes are 100% supported in html